# Multi robot collision avoidance

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, stage, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a package for ROS which solves the multi robot collision avoidance problem:
http://wiki.ros.org/multi_robot_collision_avoidance

The instructions seem so simple, but yet something is missing in them.
I try to follow them in different versions of ROS (Groovy, Hydro, Indigo, even Fuerte) but it didn't help.

The base questions are:
1 where should i git clone the packages, so that catkin_make works?
2 why there is no msg/Stall.msg and src/stageros.cpp files in my stage folder (/opt/ros/hydro/share/stage) which i should patch with stage.patch
3 which version of ROS is suitable to run this project?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209183/multi-robot-collision-avoidance/) by [Timur](https://answers.ros.org/users/22425/timur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. in your usual workspace (created as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace), under src folder (/workspace_name/src)
2. don't know (as I didn't patch stage at all, basic functionality is there without it)
3. it works under indigo.

---

Originally posted by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) with karma: 526 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1